# Having trouble while trying to prove the differentiabilty of $x^2\sin{\left(\frac 1x\right)}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let a function be defined as:

$ f(x)=x^2\sin{\left(\frac 1x\right)}$ for $x \neq 0$ and 
$ f(x)=0$ for $x=0$

I'm trying to prove that f is differentiable at 0 using the definition of derivative. However in the process of doing this I was stopped by this limit:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin\left({\frac{1}{x+h}}\right)-\sin\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right)}{h}
$$

Is it possible to solve this limit question without using l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Uhm... weren't you trying to show differentibility *at* $0$? Where does all that stuff com from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to compute that limit. Indeed
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin(1/h)
$$
which you can compute using the squeeze theorem since
$$
0\leq |h\sin(1/h)|\leq |h|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\left|\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-0}{x-0}\right|\le x$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$